# check/uncheck all the checkbox in a table

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a table that has checkbox column and I added this :

```
<th>
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
</th>
```

and here's my jQuery function :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#selectAll').click(function(){ 
   jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', jQuery('#selectAll').is(':checked')); }) 
});
```

It works fine at the first check but when i uncheck and try to check again it doesn't work! Any reason why it doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: instead of `click` event use `change` event and use `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: @user3350731 Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.prop()` and `this.checked`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#selectAll').click(function(){ 
       jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', this.checked); 
    }) 
});
```

Comment: Works great ! Could you please tell me why my code didn't work?

Comment: @user3350731 You can read from the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) docs: `As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.`

Answer (score 1):

When you choose by id on jquery it choose the first element by default, so your `jQuery('#selectAll').is(':checked')` will return the result of the first element, try using a class for selectAll instead :

```
<th>
    <input type="checkbox" class="selectAll">
</th>



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.selectAll').click(function(){ 
   jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', jQuery('.selectAll').is(':checked')); }) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
$('input#selectAll').change(function(){

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked",this.checked);

});
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4fm9f/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XuxM5/525/)**

**Html**

```
<p><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /> Check/Uncheck All</p>
<hr/>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" /> Checkbox  1
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" /> Checkbox  2
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" /> Checkbox  3
</p>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#selectAll").click(function () {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", $("#selectAll").prop("checked"))
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of using of using [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#selectAll').click(function(){ 
   jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', jQuery('#selectAll').is(':checked')); }) 
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FxEMX/)

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.